# Resize sibling divs on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I modify the size of other divs on a page when hovering over a single Div?

The end result I am trying to figure out how to do is very crudely described below.

Lets say I have a page of divs with content inside such as

```
▀ ▀ ▀ ▀

▀ ▀ ▀ ▀

▀ ▀ ▀ ▀
```

And when you hover over a div, the divs change to:

```
██▪▪▪

▪▪▪▪

▪▪▪▪
```

I am basically just wondering what the best method of completing this is, if someone could point me in the right direction, or to a previous thread.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not JavaScript expert, but I suspect that your question has nothing to do with Java and all to do with JavaScript. If I'm right, please change your tag from Java to JavaScript. Otherwise you'll confuse a lot more people like me!

Comment: You can probably combine the power of jQuery's `hover()` with `animate()` or simply assigning/unassigning various CSS classes on hover.

Comment: You write modify the size of other divs on a page when hovering over a single Div. What I see then is that all `div`'s ate 100x100, but when you hover over one, all the others become, say, 10x10? Is that what you're wanting? Or, do you mean that all are 10x10, and the one which is hovered becomes 100x100?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will take into account the possibility of using jQuery. It should be some good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a quick demo at http://jsfiddle.net/bmZKC/. It's pretty easy to do with jQuery and CSS. I used CSS3 transitions but you could easily use `$.animate` instead if you want more compatibility.

Here's the crux of it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.box:not(.active)').addClass('shrink');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('.box').removeClass('shrink');
    });
});
```

In the fiddle I only adjust the width. If you wanted to adjust the height and have them all fit together nicely I'd look into a jQuery plugin called [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the impromptu response! That and the response by DA are exactly what I was looking to accomplish. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My initial guess would be to suggest you use plain CSS.

Assuming this HTML:

```
<div id="content"><div></div><div></div>....</div>
```

This CSS may work for you:

```css
#content>div {
    display:inline-block;
    width:16px; height:16px;
    background:black;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#content {width:64px}
#content:hover>div {width:8px;height:8px}
#content>div:hover {width:24px;height:24px}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty quick with some jQuery.

Given HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    [ ... ]
</div>
```

And CSS

```
#content div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#444;
    margin:10px 12px;
}
#content .small{
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    margin:25px 27px;
}
```

Use this little piece of jQuery:

```
$("#content div").hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings().addClass("small");
    $(this).removeClass("small");
     /* This can easily be straight JavaScript if your prefer */
});
```

And get this: http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/2KrmD/

Comment: Thanks DA, that is a pretty good representation of what I am looking to do. However, could you suggest a way to "re-arrange" the other Div blocks around the highlighted object?